# git cherry-pick seems to picks up two commits from a single hash

Tags: git, cherry-pick

The below screenshot shows the result of running `git cherry-pick <hash>` while on branch `master`.

This operation is picking up two commits instead of a single commit. I don't understand why this is the case and wonder if this is a `git` bug. I am running version `2.30`.

```
git cherry-pick a2a037f311 --no-commit
```

[image: git cherry-pick]

The next screenshot shows the commit log from the branch from which I am cherry-picking.

[image: git log]

Finally, here's a diff between two consecutive commits.

```
git diff 2bad... a2a0...
```

[image: git diff]

Here's some details about the branch being cherry-picked from.

It could be I've misunderstood something, but it seems to me the only thing that should be added from this single cherry-picking operation is the line

```
Include this change!
```

The only possible thought I have is that by picking a commit in the middle of a branch history, this for some reason creates a conflict with the previous commit. But that explanation doesn't seem to really make much sense given the details of the conflict shown here.

I would have expected:

- No conflicts to occur from the cherry-pick
- A single line `Include this change!` to be added to `master` branch

Why didn't that happen?

---

#### Mergetool:

[image: mergetool]

Comment: The context for the new line in the commit you're cherry picking is different between the original parent commit and the new parent commit, so yes, the conflict is expected. I'm not sure why you got the diff markers you go, though.

Comment: The diff you're getting is more surprising, but have you tried loading it into git mergetool to see what it's showing you there?

Comment: @joanis I'm not sure how I would do that given this is a Debian linux server. It does have a GUI so I could potentially install something. Can you offer any recommendations?

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of text.

Comment: @matt the reason I have done this is to prove I have done the operations that I am claiming to have done. Otherwise no one would believe me, or others would try the same operations and claim "not reproducible". However I will type up the commands later today

Comment: Updated with the important commands, of which there are two.

Comment: The purpose of not having all of the commands in a screenshot is for two reasons: 1: So that search engines can index the content. 2: So that someone can copy and paste long commands to repeat the process for themselves. Neither is applicable here, except arguably 1 in the case of the `git cherry-pick` command, which is also in the title and body of the question, hence this string is already indexable by searches.

Comment: Screen readers cannot read screenshots.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Maybe the best thing to do here would be to share a script that reproduces this.

Comment: And `git mergetoll` should launch `vimdiff` on the machine you describe, even without a GUI.

Comment: @joanis Please see the additional screenshot. I am not familiar with this tool. Does the information shown there help?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Mergetool output, that confirms what I expected.

To explain that view, the three top windows are LOCAL, BASE and REMOTE: LOCAL is what you're trying to cherry pick onto, BASE and before the commit you're cherry picking, and REMOTE is after, so the diff you're trying to apply to LOCAL is between BASE and REMOTE. The bottom window is the current state of the file, and the one you can edit into the resolved conflict.

Here we see that BASE and LOCAL have diverged: line 10 is in BASE but not in LOCAL. The cherry-picked commit says add a line "Including this changes" after a line "Don't include this change!", but Git is finding no such in LOCAL, and so it can't figure out where to add the line. That gets flagged as a conflict.

You might think "Well, it's obvious, just add the new line at the end." But that's only obvious to a human and it's not always the correct answer. If this was actual code, I would not be willing to bet that line 11 made sense without line 10. Git merges (and cherry picks and rebases, which are variants of merging) will not assume what the correct answer is, based on just a line-by-line diff, and so it flags a conflict to ask you to provide your judgement. You can then decide if line 11 without line 10 needs to have its syntax adjusted because line 10 is not there.

Comment: Why the names Local and Remote? Does this have anything to do with literal remotes such as "origin" ?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant No. It's an alternative to "ours" and "theirs". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/163659/341994